# gdb info frame output: Wrong value for "Arglist at"?

Tags: x86, gdb, stack-trace

Just curious, but would someone be able to explain to me this `info frame` output.
Here's a toy program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int argc) {
    printf("Hello world! %d\n", argc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    foo(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the gdb `info frame` output when breaking at `foo`:

```
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x28abf0:
 eip = 0x401196 in foo (a.c:4); saved eip 0x4011c4
 called by frame at 0x28ac10
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x28abe8, args: argc=1
 Locals at 0x28abe8, Previous frame's sp is 0x28abf0
 Saved registers:
  ebp at 0x28abe8, eip at 0x28abec
(gdb) p &argc
$1 = (int *) 0x28abf0
(gdb)
```

Why are locals and arglist at the same location?  As far as I understand,
`Locals at` should denote the current ebp value as the upper-bound address
for the locals of the current frame (which it does).  But why does arglist
point to the same location?  Based on printing `&argc`, the value for
`Arglist at` definitely doesn't seem to point to the arguments.

As an aside, I do understand the x86 calling convention and the structure
of the stack frames.  It just seemed odd to me that all the online
info frames I could find had identical `Arglist at` and `Locals at` values,
but only this one lonely post about this inconsistency:

http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/gdb-info-frames-arglist-locals-address-782598.html

At any rate, wondering to some degree whether there's a known reason
for this, and/or how one actually goes about posting a gdb bug.  Thanks!

Comment: wow only one upvote. i ran into the same issue :/

Answer (score 2):

This output is just a relic from pre-DWARF days.  It ought to just be removed, at least in some cases.  See the remarkably pithy gdb bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13260